# linux terminal transfer control to new terminal

Tags: command-line, xterm

in one of my shell program, I want start an xterm window from terminal and then the control  of next execution should go to the newly opened window (by default the control will be in the terminal). How to do this using command line arguments (not by moving mouse pointer to the new window :) ) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "control"?  Do you mean focus?  Do you want to run a given command in the new window?

Comment: What window manager / desktop environment do you run?  This behavior (focus of new windows) is going to be determined by the configuration of your WM / DE.

Comment: @Andy Dalton yes I want to run a command on new window

Comment: actually not 1 command, the subsequent commands must be executed from the new window.

Comment: So if you were simply to start typing, the commands should end up in the new window? This is called "focus" and because it is managed by the WM/DE you're going to need to tell us which one you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a new xterm and run a sequence of commands in that window, you can use the `-e` option.  If you want the xterm to remain open after the command is executed, you can include the `-hold` option.

For example:

```
xterm -hold -e 'pwd; ls'
```

Comment: Similar question were asked at askubuntu [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the). More information about other terminal emulator were also discussed.

Answer (score 2):

`Screen` is a full-screen software program that can be used to multiplexes a physical console between several processes (typically interactive shells). It offers a user to open several separate terminal instances inside a one single terminal window manager.

The screen application is very useful, if you are dealing with multiple programs from a command line interface and for separating programs from the terminal shell. It also allows you to share your sessions with others users and detach/attach terminal sessions.

`apt-get install screen` (Debian based systems)

`yum install screen` (Red Hat based systems)

Ref: http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/

Comment: The successor is `tmux` and it's even more powerful.